# Applying for a new job with intention to relocate in future

Tags: recruitment, europe

In the last year, I changed the job and moved to another country. The decision was dictated by social security and political changes in my home country.
Both countries are in the European Union and I work as a software developer.

I'm not happy with the outcome and I'm considering both changing the job again and maybe moving back. In the current job, I'm unsatisfied with the job organization and business area I work in. In terms of my new country, I didn't realize how much I would be affected by being disconnected from my family and friends.

Given the above circumstances, I believe the most favorable outcome for me is finding a new employer, who would allow me to work from another country.
I identified some companies which have offices in both countries.

My question is how to raise this issue during the interview and still be viewed as a valuable candidate?

Should I say it right at the beginning of the recruitment process or rather at the end?

Should I even say it all?

I think it is best to communicate upfront that in the future I might want to relocate to another country and still work for the company. In case of a decision of moving back, I prefer to keep a job so as not to have short periods of employment in my CV.

Comment: What sort of time frame are you looking at?  If you've got a 1 month notice period and it takes a month to get hired so you'd be looking at starting a new job in 2 months but you'd expect that you'd be making the decision to move 6 months from now, that's different than if your plans are more nebulous and it may be years before you decide.

Comment: No, don't say it. At least, don't say it unless it's absolutely necessary for logistical reasons and unless you're absolutely sure they're going to hire you. Use the address of a friend in the meantime to put on your resume. And make sure to get a mobile number with an area code that the new potential employers will recognize as being local. Otherwise, your resume will just get filtered out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't mention it. I also wouldn't assume that I could transfer between countries even if a company does have offices in both locations.

As a hiring manager in Country A, I'm trying to fill a position in my team. If you tell me you're going to want to move in 6 months, then that means I have to start the recruitment process again. Software developers are not particularly productive for the first few months while they adapt to the software stack and learn about the business domain. From the point of view of me and my team you are not a good choice.

When you are ready to return to Country B, will the team based there have any vacancies? Will the local manager want you to join their team? How transferable will your skills be? Are you working on the same piece of software, or are the two offices effectively different companies who just happen to be have the same owner?

**What else could you do?**

We're in a pandemic and software developers are working from home anyway. Apply for a fully-remote position that allows you to work from either Country A or Country B. When you move you'll need to inform HR for tax purposes, but you won't need to switch teams. This solves the problems I've mentioned above, so I would discuss this during the recruitment process (it's no longer a significant negative for the company).

Answer (score 3):

> Should I even say it all?

The simple answer is no, don't say it.  It's your private business, not theirs.

> (If I say this, would I) still be viewed as a valuable candidate?

My guess is they'd just cross you off the list. Your intuition is correct. Nobody wants to hire someone who's actual goal is just moving around between offices.

Keep your personal future goals to yourself. Enjoy your new situation.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I say it right at the beginning of the recruitment process or rather at the end?

I would bring it up early. If it's a "must have" for you and if it's a non-starter for the company it's not going to work out regardless of what happens in the interview process. In this case bringing it up late just waste's everyone's time and effort (including yours) and may burn bridges with a potential future employer.

Almost all job postings have one or more "job locations". Applying to a job with a location that you don't want to work at is a losing proposition. Why not apply directly to the location you actually want to work? Why do you need the employer to have an office in your current country as well ?

Comment: The problem is I would like to change my current job in the near future, let's say within one year. 
I am still not sure what is the best option for me, staying in a new country or moving back.  Therefore an employer with offices in both countries would be perfect for me. I could treat the relocation as an available option, which I could use if I make such a decision.

Answer (score 2):

> ... and I'm considering both changing the job again and maybe moving back...

Figure out if you want to move back or not then act on that decision.

Bringing up this concern to the hiring manager will sound like someone trying to get a date using a line like this...

> I’m just getting off a bad relationship and want to get into a better one, and right now, your good friend that lives in the country that I might want to live in is looking mighty fine to me...would you date me so that you can hook us up later when I decide on what I want to do?